# JavaScript values can be passed back and forth between frames in the same web page?

Tags: javascript

"JavaScript values can be passed back and forth between frames in the same web page. This becomes a problem only when you try to identify the type of a reference value, because each web page has its own global context — its own version of Object, Array, and all other built-in types. As a result, when you pass an array from one frame to another, instanceof doesn’t work because the array is actually an instance of Array from a different frame."

I was reading some Js book when I came across the above passage. I don't quite understand what "values can be passed back and forth between frames in the same web..." means, is the "frame" here as in 60frames/sec? And if yes, what does passing value between frames mean? Can anyone show me an example of "passing values between frames"?

Comment: I am assuming they are referring to an [HTML frame element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frame) but more specifically [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: Frames/sec is not the right context here, frames are basically "panels" on a web page that load different pages individually. Specifically, look into an <iframe>: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: "Frame" in this context refers to HTML "Frames", as in: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html

Answer (score 0):

this means that you can pass back and forth a js variable between the `<iframe>` elements that are children of your window. there are limitations specially when a frame has its source in a different domain.